# How do I remove the Me-User-Indicator from the Panel?

Tags: indicator

How do I remove the Me-User-Indicator from the Panel?

The indicator contains two items: the written user name and the icon of a human.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

### How to

1. Install `dconf-tools` and then run `dconf-editor` from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. logout and login

Answer (score 2):

Command-line version of fossfreedom's answer:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf write /apps/indicator-session/user-show-menu false
```

Answer (score 1):

## 14.04

It's easy via GUI and commandline:

### From GUI

1. Install [dconf Editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-editor);
2. Open the app and go to **apps** > **indicator-session** from the sidebar;
3. Uncheck **user-show-menu**.

To undo the change, simply check it again.

### From Command-line

1. Open a Terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>;
2. Run:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false
   ```

To undo the change, run `gsettings reset com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu`.

[image: remove list of users]